# How do I tell if .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed?

Tags: .net-3.5, installation

How can I find out if SP1 has been installed on a server which has .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use Add/Remove programs from the Control Panel.

Comment: Go figure. Later, I thought I missed a "programatically" point to your question, Guy.

Answer (score 140):

Look at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\`. One of these must be true:

- The `Version` value in that key should be **3.5.30729.01**
- Or the `SP` value in the same key should be **1**

In C# (taken from the first comment), you could do something along these lines:

```
const string name = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5";
RegistryKey subKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(name);
var version = subKey.GetValue("Version").ToString();
var servicePack = subKey.GetValue("SP").ToString();
```

Comment: const string name = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5";
RegistryKey subKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(name);

var version = subKey.GetValue("Version").ToString();
var servicePack = subKey.GetValue("SP").ToString();

Comment: On my machine, `Version` is `3.5.30729.5420` and `SP` is `1`

Comment: On the command line:  
`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" /V Version`  
`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" /V SP`

Comment: There will be a problem: if a user don't have .NET installed, how do your program written with .NET **run** to detect if .NET is installed?

Answer (score 27):

You could go to [SmallestDotNet](http://www.smallestdotnet.com) using IE from the server. That will tell you the version and also provide a download link if you're out of date.

Comment: Only tells you the highest version though, e.g. if you have 4, it wont tell you whether you also have 3.5 sp 1

Answer (score 12):

I came to this page while trying to figure out how to detect the framework versions installed on a server without access to remote desktop or registry, so Danny V's answer worked for me.

```
string path = System.Environment.SystemDirectory;
path = path.Substring( 0, path.LastIndexOf('\\') );
path = Path.Combine( path, "Microsoft.NET" );
// C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\

string[] versions = new string[]{
    "Framework\\v1.0.3705",
    "Framework64\\v1.0.3705",
    "Framework\\v1.1.4322",
    "Framework64\\v1.1.4322",
    "Framework\\v2.0.50727",
    "Framework64\\v2.0.50727",
    "Framework\\v3.0",
    "Framework64\\v3.0",
    "Framework\\v3.5",
    "Framework64\\v3.5",
    "Framework\\v3.5\\Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1",
    "Framework64\\v3.5\\Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1",
    "Framework\\v4.0",
    "Framework64\\v4.0"
};

foreach( string version in versions )
{
    string versionPath = Path.Combine( path, version );

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo( versionPath );
    if( dir.Exists )
    {
        Response.Output.Write( "{0}<br/>", version );
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked as expected for me. Just created a new website project, added the code and put it on the share, then requested the page.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/frameworkversiondetection.aspx) which shows the registry keys you need to look for and provides a .NET library that will do this for you.

First, you should to determine if .NET 3.5 is installed by looking at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\Install, which is a DWORD value. If that value is present and set to 1, then that version of the Framework is installed.

Look at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\SP, which is a DWORD value which indicates the Service Pack level (where 0 is no service pack).

To be correct about things, you really need to ensure that .NET Fx 2.0 and .NET Fx 3.0 are installed first and then check to see if .NET 3.5 is installed. If all three are true, then you can check for the service pack level.

Comment: article link is changed, here it is the new location: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/frameworkversiondetection.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Check is the following directory exists:

In 64bit machines:
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1\

In 32bit machines:
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1\

Where %SYSTEMROOT% is the SYSTEMROOT enviromental variable (e.g. C:\Windows).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the name is everywhere "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1", you can use this:

```
string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
{
    return rk.GetSubKeyNames().Contains("Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1");
}
```

Comment: +1, the easiest way so far to programmatically check if 3.5 SP1 is installed - actually, if it worked. I tried it, it doesn't work for me, it always returns false.

Comment: Skimming through the collection returned by GetSubKeyNames(), the plain text name is used for some products, for some - like the .net frameworks, the product ids {1ea1f-...} are being used. That's why it can't be found.