# Is .NET included in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7

Is the .NET Framework included in Windows 7? If so, which version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current Beta includes .net 3.5. Not sure if SP1 or not though.

Answer (score 5):

Beta 1 (7000) of win7 has .NET 3.5 version 3.5.30729.715

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198931/how-do-i-tell-if-net-35-sp1-is-installed), that means it has SP1 with a few more (most likely minor win7-specific) changes.

I'd anticipate that for the final release this will stay the same, but the final 715 number (which isn't used for anything) might go up

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that if it is not included already (because it is just a beta), that it will eventually have it included.

As far as the version, I would guess 3.5 SP1 or potentially 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 included .NET 3.5 SP1