# Checking MVC.net is installed from Web Setup Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, setup-project, web-setup-project

Does anyone know of an elegant way to check form a web setup project (as a pre condition maybe?) that MVC.net is installed on the target machine? Is the registry the best way? Or a windows installer search?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1) MVC doesn't technically require installation. If you have .NET 3.5 (without SP1), it can be bin deployed.

2) However, to see if it's already installed, [test for .NET 3.5 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198931/how-do-i-tell-if-net-3-5-sp1-is-installed).