# How to use TypeForwardedTo in Portable Class Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

I'm trying to build a Portable Class Library which uses implementations from the platform when available.  For example, `Lazy<T>` is available on .NET 4.5, Windows Store Apps, Windows Phone 8, BUT it's not available on Windows Phone 7, Silverlight 4.  When my PCL is loaded on one of the platforms that has a `Lazy<T>` implementation, I want to use the platform's implementation.  When it's not available on the platform, I want to use my own implementation. It seems to be possible because the Microsoft BCL is doing it, but I haven't figured out how to implement it.

I've read that by using the `TypeForwardedToAttribute`, you can redirect the PCL to use the implementation from the platform.  I'm not quite sure how to configure my Visual Studio Projects to achieve this result.  If **CoreLib** is my library, and **ShimLib** contains my implementation of `Lazy<T>`. Where do I add the TypeForwardedToAttribute? The attribute requires an actual Type reference `typeof(System.Lazy<>)`, which doesn't work when Windows Phone 7 is targeted in the PCL.  If I remove Windows Phone 7, then I can't add a reference from CoreLib to ShimLib because ShimLib doesn't support all the platforms that CoreLib does. How do I handle this?

Yes, I know `Lazy<T>` is super easy to implement, but it's just an example, and my actual situation applies to many more classes that are less trivial to implement.

Comment: [TypeForwardedTo] does not actually solve the underlying deployment problem.  In the case of PCL, it is Microsoft that takes care of deploying the assembly that may or may not contain the [TypeForwardedTo], based on the platform.  You won't get the same help for your own forwarded class.

Comment: Lazy<T> is "super easy to implement" if you disregard [LazyThreadSafetyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode(v=vs.110).aspx). Don't worry I got you covered: [Theraot's Lazy<T> for .NET 3.5 or previous](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/blob/master/Core/System/Lazy1.net35.cs) For an alternative see [LazyNeedle<T>](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/blob/master/Core/Theraot/Threading/Needles/LazyNeedle.cs) (please report any bugs). *full disclosure*: Yes, I'm the same Threaot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way Microsoft.Bcl does this by shipping two assemblies with the same identity; one with the type itself, and one with the type forward. You reference the one with the type when targeting platforms that don't support Lazy (include portable library combinations that include one of these platforms). And reference the one with the type-forward when targeting platforms with Lazy, this enables to consume libraries built against the older platforms.

Make note, Microsoft.Bcl has a little advantage that you don't have. We ship an assembly that has the same identity as one that is already in later versions, which means that when a Windows Phone 7 *app* runs on Windows Phone 8, they get the version that's built in, not the one in the shim library. You are unable to mimic that, but that's probably something you can live with in your situation.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to mimic, and not being able to reproduce the identity of the BCL seems to be what's killing me.  Makes sense to me now.  

Lazy was just an example that I thought would be easy to illustrate.  My actual implementation is trying to shim Windows.Storage APIs for WP7, so that I can write to one storage API for WP8, W8, and WP7.  On W8 I want my public API to expose the types from the real Windows.Storage.  On WP7 they'd be my implementation of StorageFile, StorageFolder, etc.

Comment: Oh, I understand your problem. Windows.Storage is going to be close to impossible to mimic. It's a WinRT API. WinRT is bound by the compiler differently than traditional .NET APIs, which will be impossible to mimic on Windows Phone 7, because the runtime doesn't know anything about it. Instead for that, I'd suggest using something like Daniel Plaisted's PCL Storage which provides wrappers for the IO APIs: http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5):

The principle idea of type forwarding is very well explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553463/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-typeforwardedtoattribute) question and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67999/Forwarding-a-type-from-one-assembly-to-another-Typ) article and I'm not repeating the details here. In summary, however, the idea is to be able to reuse a library `A` **without** recompiling, even though it references a library `B` that **is being replaced** by library `C`. To that end, library `B` has to be modified such that it forwards the reference to library `C`, which is exactly what the TypeForwardedTo attribute does.

How does this help you? Well, you could create your `ShimLib` such that it is referenced by all your projects, but uses conditional compilation and type forwarding to link it to the framework libraries if they exist. Fortunately, [someone already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462419/compatibility-pack-for-backporting-new-net-framework-features) [that for you](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot) :)

**Edit** in response to Matt's comment: You're right, I overlooked that Theraot doesn't fall back to the original implementation. And I guess that will be very hard to achieve without recompiling. The best you can do is probably to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923210/c-sharp-conditional-compilation-and-framework-targets) strategy, i.e. to have different build configurations for the different framework versions. That way, you can conditionally compile the `TypeForwardedToAttribute`. At least, this saves you from having to duplicate code. If you **really** don't want to distribute different versions of your code, you might implement a bootstraper that [determines the framework version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899707/way-to-determine-framework-version-without-registry) and loads the version of your assembly that has been compiled using the build configuration for this version

Comment: I get conceptually how the TypeForwardedTo attribute works, and yes I've gotten it to work in normal assemblies. The problem I'm having is combining that with Portable Class Libraries. 


Theraot is interesting, but it's not a PCL and it doesn't defer to the framework's implementation if it exists.  It's creating libraries for specific versions of the framework. 


What I'm shooting for is like Microsoft.Bcl (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) where Phone7 uses BCL's portable implementation of Task, but Phone8 and WinRuntime use the framework's implementation of Task

Comment: Thanks bigge. The different build configurations is close, but I can't change the target frameworks property of the PCL project per configuration.  It's set once for the project regardless of the configuration.  If I can't change the target framework to exclude WP7, then I get build errors because the compiler can't resolve System.Lazy in the TypeForwardedTo attribute. Perhaps creating multiple projects which generate the same assemblyname is the only strategy.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923210/c-sharp-conditional-compilation-and-framework-targets/2928835#2928835

Comment: @MattDotson and bigge it is true that there is a lack of the aforementioned fallback... in fact you gave me an idea... I could make a façade assembly that targets .NET 2.0 (so you can include it from most projects) have that one detect and call the right assembly. That adds overhead, yet is is optional to use it. What do you think about that? (It will require a lot of testing, though). About PCL... I'll get to it. Note: Aside from System.Threading.Tasks, I'm currently looking forward to target .NET Compact Framework (no date on that).