# How can I tell if asp.net 4.0 is installed on my server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I'm leasing a server from 1and1, and I can't get into the regedit.   How can I tell if asp.net is installed, or if I need to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I tell if .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198931/how-do-i-tell-if-net-3-5-sp1-is-installed)

If you can get to Add/Remove Programs on the control panel it should be listed there under:

```
Microsoft ASP.Net xxx
```

I have the version number 1.0.20105.0 in the control panel which is at least 4.0.

You could also go to "IIS" -> "Application Pools" -> Click on the "DefaultAppPool" and select "Basic Settings"; then under ".NET Framework version:" see if ".Net Framework v.4x" is there

Comment: Thanks Click. but there is not 'start' button, so I cannot add/remove programs ...

Comment: I've updated the answer with another method; can you get to IIS?

Comment: It looks like you can do it programmatically as well; you could write a quick app and deploy it to find out:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ProgrammaticallyDetermineWhatVersionOfASPNETYoureRunning.aspx

Comment: Thanks for helpinng Click.... I got to start / control panel ... add / remove programs .... but it won't let me add dotNetFx40_Full_setup on this Windows 2008 server.

Comment: Ah that sucks; do you have to request permission to install programs on the server?

Answer (score 5):

If you have internet access and IE, browse to http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/ in IE. It will tell you which .net you have installed.

See my screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Robert .... it says I already have ,net installed ... but thanks for taking the time to provide with that link!