# how check is .NET framework installed or not

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, visual-c++, installation

I want to develop a .NET application in c# but first i need to check
that the .NET framework is installed , because i don't want user see any error.
so is there any vc++ code that only use MFC in a static Library to check if .NET framework is installed ?

Comment: You may check this in installer. There are plugins for all popular installers to check this.

Comment: Which is the lowest Windows version you support? Depending on that the .NET framework (in at least version 2.0) will usually be installed. Concerning: "I don't want user see any error". What else do you want to happen when you, hypothetically, have detected that the .NET framework is not present? Silently install it?

Comment: Additionally, you may add the framework installation into your installer after check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell if .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198931/how-do-i-tell-if-net-3-5-sp1-is-installed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the registry to check about .net framework and it's version, Either you you use `VC++` or some other language that can handle registry..

Check Micrsoft Knowledge Base Article - [How to determine which versions and service pack levels of the Microsoft .NET Framework are installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785)

There are various way suggested on [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed).

Another one is using the Signum.Utilities library from SignumFramework (wich you can use stand-alone), you can get it nicely and without dealing with the registry by yourself.

**Edit:** Check this code project article - [Is .NET Framework installed on this machine???](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18574/Is-NET-Framework-installed-on-this-machine), it is also using registry to get the framework installed or not..

Hope this help..

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if the file `MSCorEE.dll` is present in the
   *`%SystemRoot%\System32`* directory.
2. Also the .Net Framework SDk includes a utility called **CLRver.exe**
   which shows versions of .Net framework installed on your machine