# Check .NET Framework presense

Tags: .net, windows, .net-3.5

I have managed application targeted for .NET Framework 3.5.
I need it to display messagebox with some text and download link if user don't have the framework installed.
What is the right and simple way to do this?

So far I see nothing better than writing native bootstrapper that will check presence of the framework and show messagebox otherwise.

Comment: This is something that your installer should implement surely?

Comment: You could also provide this information at the same location your user finds your application, i.e. a web site.

Comment: My app doesn't have an installer. May be this is wrong but I can do nothing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [registry to check about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714331/how-check-is-net-framework-installed-or-not) .net framework and it's version
**Ref:**
[How to determine which versions and service pack levels of the Microsoft .NET Framework are installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785)

Edit: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198959/770710) on SO thread [How do I tell if .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198931/how-do-i-tell-if-net-3-5-sp1-is-installed).